# Why hybrid GIS application gets GPS position only from Google & not from the device

Tags: leaflet, android

I have built a GIS application using Leaflet on the web, after I put this web application to run on Android as a hybrid GIS application I made the application work with offline basemap (offline usage only) but the GPS finder can't get the position it trys to retreive it fom the Internet and not from the device.
is it because my GIS application isn't Native android ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android GPS works native in hybrid apps, it just needs some settings within app. I'm absolute amateur with Android apps, I learned how to use Android Studio only for the purpose of writing hybrid Andriod app that uses Leaflet.

Below are GPS related excerpts from my hybrid app that worked for me.

Manifest:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
...
```

Code:

```
...
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                            GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
      // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
      // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
      callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
  }
...
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
...
```

After installing app on Android you also have to allow it to use GPS.

Comment: I have this same code and GPS signal needs always an internet connection to get the location

Comment: @RabieBen Ups, I forgot permissions that have to be added in manifest. They are included now in the above example.

Comment: @RabieBen Did you manage to solve this problem?